# Join between two tables, number of row

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I hope you're well.

I try to write a sql query with a join between two tables like below :

> table1 (id_master, id) 
>   1,1
>   1,2
>   1,3
>   1,4
>   1,5

And the second table

> table2 (id_master, id) 
>   1,1
>   1,2
>   1,3
>   1,4

As you can see, each table contain ID_master & id.
The table2 contains the acknownledgement (ack) of table1. Each row in the table1 must have an "ack" in the table2.

In my example, I have no result because (table1 (1,5) hasn't got an ack in table2 and I want result when table1.row (1,5) has got a ack in table2.

I have tried with join but i have result when we have the first "ack". I want have result when I have all "ack".

I hope to be clear.

thanks for your help.

kind regards

EDIT :

Thanks stripathi & jpw,

Example1:

> table1 (id_master, id)
>   1,A
>   1,B
>   1,C
>   2,D
>   2,E

the second table

> table2 (id_master, id)
>   1,A
>   1,B
>   2,D
>   2,E

My query's result must be :

> 2,D
>   2,E

Because we can find the rows(2,D) & (2,E) in the two tables,  but it isn't the case for (1,*) (it miss the (1,C) in the table2).

Comment: Didn't get your question.
From what I understand, you need to do If Not Exists(Table1 except (Table1 inner join Table2)) and put logic in the block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think both of these two queries should do what you want, and they seem to work using Oracle 11g R2 (see this [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0431a/6)). Note that the result might be wrong if the second table contains items that are not present in the first table.

```
select * 
from table1 
where id_master in (
  select a.id_master 
  from table1 a
  group by a.id_master
  having count(distinct a.id) = (
    select count(distinct b.id) 
    from table2 b
    where a.id_master = b.id_master
    group by b.id_master
  )
);

select * 
from table1 a 
where not exists (
  select id from Table1 where id_master = a.id_master
  minus 
  select id from Table2
);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you using oracle you can use `ROWNUM` to get row number of `first ack`. You can try this :

```
SELECT ID,ID_MASTER FROM(
    SELECT ID,ID_MASTER,ROWNUM RR
    FROM TABLE2 
    ORDER BY ID_MASTER,ID ASC) T2
WHERE RR >= (
    SELECT R FROM(
        SELECT ID_MASTER,ID, ROWNUM R
        FROM TABLE1
        ORDER BY ID_MASTER,ID ASC
    ) T1
    WHERE T1.ID_MASTER||T1.ID NOT IN(SELECT ID_MASTER||ID FROM TABLE2)
)
```

Comment: @jpw Oh i see, i updated my answer. `ROWNUM` must have an alias.